# How to close other expanded rows when some other row is expanded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am working on Jqgrid in ASP.NET MVC.

I have managed to have a server side paging and sorting for a subgrid.

**Scenario**

I have a collection of rows each with a open subgrid option, I go and click on the '+' expand first row the subgrid for first expands, now I click on the '+' expand third row.

Here I want the first row's subgrid to collapse.

**In Short : This mean that only row's subgrid should stay expanded.**

I am not sure how to get going about this.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I think u missed this "I am not sure how to get going about this." and you should include this link next time you write http://www.whathaveyoutried.com :P

Comment: That's a great link, and I probably will include it the next time I say that. The question still stands though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create all expanders with same class + class that will determine weather it is expanded or not. On expander click you will fire event which will remove expanded and collapsed classes from elements which have expander class and attach collapsed and only clicked expander will get expanded class. I will post example

```
<div class="expander collapsed">
    <div class="expander-title" onclick="$('expander').removeClass('expanded collapsed').addClass('collapsed'); $(this).removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded')">
       title here
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       content here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.expanded > .content {
    display: block;
}

.collapsed > .content {
    display: none;
}
```

This is one expander

Comment: I have not tried that code, but I have done similiar thing and worked great, I hope I have not made any little mistake :)